# Trying to get unique records with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is looking at a 'page_views' table.  And I so far have the ability to get the total views by day.  However, I am having an issue with getting unique views by day.

The column I am testing against is user_id... Here's the query I have for total views.

```
SELECT 
  site_id, 
  CONCAT(  month(created_at) 
         , '-'
         ,   day(created_at)
         , '-' 
         , year(created_at)
        ) as created_at_date, 
  COUNT(*) as total_results 
FROM 
  page_views 
GROUP BY day(created_at)
```

I can't figure out the logic to just get the total unique views by day unique being based on the user_id column.

```
Schema:

id:int
user_id:int
site_id:int
request_uri:varchar
referer:varchar
user_agent:varchar
created_at:datetime
```

Comment: Can you paste your table schema?

Comment: @Joshmattvander - site_id appears in your query, but not the schema - what's the significance of that?

Comment: I edited the schema.  The site_id corresponds to a particular site a user might be viewing a (WHERE site_id='1') for example.  But more importantly I just need uniqueness by the user_id who is viewing.

Answer (score 2):

First, your original query is not correct. (it will return invalid results in the same days of different months or for different sites) It should be as belows

```
SELECT 
  site_id, 
  CONCAT(month(created_at) , '-',   day(created_at), '-' , year(created_at)) 
                                                         as created_at_date, 
  COUNT(*) as total_results 
FROM 
  page_views 
GROUP BY 
  site_id, 
  CONCAT(month(created_at) , '-',   day(created_at), '-' , year(created_at))
```

And for the original question, below query should work :

```
SELECT 
  site_id, 
  CONCAT(month(created_at) , '-',   day(created_at), '-' , year(created_at))
                                                           as created_at_date, 
  COUNT(distinct user_id) as unique_users
FROM 
  page_views 
GROUP BY 
  site_id, 
  CONCAT(month(created_at) , '-',   day(created_at), '-' , year(created_at))
```

Comment: +1 But couldn't you do the group by on a 'date(created_at)'. Feels like that should be a bit faster.

Comment: Yes, you are right it will be faster. But if you are going for strict SQL, all non-aggregate the items in the select clause should appear in the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use the [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function instead of CONCAT:

```
SELECT
    site_id,
    DATE_FORMAT( created_at, '%m-%d-%Y' ) AS created_at_date,
    COUNT( DISTINCT user_id ) AS unique_users
FROM
    page_views
GROUP BY
    site_id,
    DATE_FORMAT( created_at, '%m-%d-%Y' )
```

Note that (as xycf7 mentions) your posted query groups by day-of-month, which would show you at most 31 groups - which may not be what you intended.